# Is a derived class considered a member of the base class?

Tags: c++

I was reading about the [NVI Idiom](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Non-Virtual_Interface) and most examples follow this form

```
#include <iostream>

class Base {
public:
    virtual ~Base() = default;

    void do_something() {
        do_something_impl();
    }

private:
    virtual void do_something_impl() = 0;
};

class Derived : public Base {
private:
    void do_something_impl() override {
        std::cout << "Hello, world!\n";
    }
};

void foo(Base& b) {
    b.do_something();
}

int main() {
    Derived d;
    foo(d);
}
```

I have always had it in my head that "A private member of a class is only accessible to the members and friends of that class" (from [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/access)), When `do_something_impl` is implemented in `Derived`, is the access specifier not taken into consideration? Or is `Derived` a member of `Base`? Does implementing a virtual function not count as "accessing"? I'm not sure which part of the language allows this.

Comment: I can't say with too much technical certainty but virtual functions are different. It's not accessing the method, it's redefining it. I'm sure there is a better way to say it.

Comment: I'm guessing I missed something when I learned about inheritance. Since `do_something_impl` is pure virtual, it has to be implemented _somewhere_ in `Derived` - and the access specifier shouldn't disallow that. Maybe this is a symptom of only ever using public virtual functions - I've never thought about private ones.

Comment: `private` isn't quite the straight jacket they teach it as. There are many ways to circumvent it. It's there to make it hard to shoot yourself in the foot, but you can still do it with a bigger gun. In this case, the function exists, and that's pretty much all that matters.

Comment: If anyone's looking for a Standard reference, [\[class.virtual\]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/class.virtual) just allows it by saying nothing about access level in the definition of a function "override", but does have [a footnote](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/class.virtual#footnote-111) mentioning that access control is not considered.

Comment: Thank you. I'll stop looking now. Are you canonizing that as an answer? I think this deserves one or a dupe.

Comment: I often saw `virtual` functions being `protected` (what gives access to derived classes (and friends) exclusively). Though, there might be yet another reason for this: Where I saw this - e.g. in Qt event handlers - there is always the potential need to call the corresponding member function of the base class in the override.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [**this**](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/virtual#In_detail) *[emphasis added]*:

> > If some member function `vf` is declared as virtual in a class Base, and some class Derived, which is derived, directly or indirectly, from Base, has a declaration for member function with the same
> >
> > - name
> > - parameter type list (but not the return type)
> > - cv-qualifiers
> > - ref-qualifiers
> >
> > Then this function in the class Derived is also virtual (whether or not the keyword virtual is used in its declaration) and overrides `Base::vf` (whether or not the word override is used in its declaration).
> >
> > `Base::vf` **does not need to be accessible or visible to be overridden.** (`Base::vf` **can be declared private, or Base can be inherited using private inheritance.** Any members with the same name in a base class of Derived which inherits Base do not matter for override determination, even if they would hide `Base::vf` during name lookup.)

```
class B {
    virtual void do_f(); // private member
 public:
    void f() { do_f(); } // public interface
};
struct D : public B {
    void do_f() override; // overrides B::do_f
};

int main()
{
    D d;
    B* bp = &d;
    bp->f(); // internally calls D::do_f();
}
```

Comment: That was strange wording, since "visible" is not related to "private". "Visible" means "not hidden by other declarations in name lookup", and "accessible" relates to public/protected/private rules. I've updated that paragraph on the wiki.

Answer (score 3):

Overriding the virtual function does not count as accessing. However if you need to call the base implementation, that would be impossible to do from Derived.

```
class Base {
public:
    virtual ~Base() = default;

    void do_something() {
        do_something_impl();
    }

private:
    virtual void do_something_impl() { /*Default implementation*/ }
};

class Derived : public Base {
private:
    void do_something_impl() override {
        //Base::do_something_impl() is not accessible from here:
        //Base::do_something_impl();
        std::cout << "Hello, world!\n";
    }
};
```